# Can I break in a method marked with DebuggerStepThrough attribute?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

The DebuggerStepThrough attribute tells the debugger to skip the method, but what if I really want to step in it, and I don't want to remove the attribute?

Is there any way to do that in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Pressing F12 to go to the method definition, and then putting a breakpoint on the opening curly brace before stepping seems to work fine.

Comment: It doesnt for me, and MSDN says otherwise. Do you have any special settings? 
  
"Behavior in Visual Studio 2010 is different than Visual Studio 2005
In Visual Studio 2010 the debugger ignores breakpoints in methods marked with DebuggerStepThroughAttribute. This is different than the behavior stated for VisualStudio 2005."

Comment: Strange. Works just fine for me in Win7 VS2010